# Detect whole word in NSStrings

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

How do I detect if an NSString contains a specific word, e.g. `is`.

If the NSString is `Here is my string. His isn't a mississippi isthmus. It is...`? The method should detect the word `is` and return `YES`.

However, if the NSString is `His isn't a mississipi isthmus`, it should return `NO`.

I tried using `if ([text rangeOfString:@"is" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) { ... }` but it detects characters not words.

Comment: Surrounding the searched word with a space will not detect the last is...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use "regular expression" search with the "word boundary pattern" `\b`:

```
NSString *text = @"Here is my string. His isn't a mississippi isthmus. It is...";
NSString *pattern = @"\\bis\\b";
NSRange range = [text rangeOfString:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) { ... }
```

This works also for cases like `"Is it?"` or `"It is!"`, where the word is not surrounded by spaces.

In **Swift 2** this would be

```
let text = "Here is my string. His isn't a mississippi isthmus. It is..."
let pattern = "\\bis\\b"
if let range = text.rangeOfString(pattern, options: [.RegularExpressionSearch, .CaseInsensitiveSearch]) {
    print ("found:", text.substringWithRange(range))
}
```

**Swift 3:**

```
let text = "Here is my string. His isn't a mississippi isthmus. It is..."
let pattern = "\\bis\\b"
if let range = text.range(of: pattern, options: [.regularExpression, .caseInsensitive]) {
    print ("found:", text.substring(with: range))
}
```

**Swift 4:**

```
let text = "Here is my string. His isn't a mississippi isthmus. It is..."
let pattern = "\\bis\\b"
if let range = text.range(of: pattern, options: [.regularExpression, .caseInsensitive]) {
    print ("found:", text[range])
}
```

**Swift 5** (using the new raw string literals):

```
let text = "Here is my string. His isn't a mississippi isthmus. It is..."
let pattern = #"\bis\b"#
if let range = text.range(of: pattern, options: [.regularExpression, .caseInsensitive]) {
    print ("found:", text[range])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSRegularExpressionSearch` option with `\b` to match word boundary characters.

Like this:

```
NSString *string = @"Here is my string. His isn't a mississippi isthmus. It is...";
if(NSNotFound != [string rangeOfString:@"\\bis\\b" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch].location) {//...}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
if ([text rangeOfString:@" is " options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions, as suggested, or you could analyze the words linguistically:

```
NSString *string = @"Here is my string. His isn't a mississippi isthmus. It is...";
__block BOOL containsIs = NO;
[string enumerateLinguisticTagsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) scheme:NSLinguisticTagSchemeTokenType options:NSLinguisticTaggerOmitPunctuation | NSLinguisticTaggerOmitWhitespace | NSLinguisticTaggerOmitOther orthography:nil usingBlock:^(NSString *tag, NSRange tokenRange, NSRange sentenceRange, BOOL *stop){
    NSString *substring = [string substringWithRange:tokenRange];
    if (containsIs)
        if ([substring isEqualToString:@"n't"])
            containsIs = NO; // special case because "isn't" are actually two separate words
        else
            *stop = YES;
    else
        containsIs = [substring isEqualToString:@"is"];
}];
NSLog(@"'%@' contains 'is': %@", string, containsIs ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```